# chrome.bookmarks item's id is unique over all computers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Chrome.bookmarks Docs says

> The unique identifier for the node. IDs are unique within the current
>   profile, and they remain valid even after the browser is restarted.

I thought IDs are unique for my user profile regardless where I log in. But after some experiments I found IDs of bookmarks item's are different among different computers. And not duplicated.

Does this happen cause I misunderstood the phrase?

Comment: guess it depends on what you interpret `current profile` means - I took it to mean the current profile on the current computer and not anything to do with my google profile

Comment: thanks for the reply. I guess it is.

Comment: im facing the same problem, it says unique by profile but the profile is offline, not the auth'ed profile thus 2 devices have 2 different profiles, kinda